# How to extract a value from function in swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I've written a function in swift which gives me a numeric value from JSON api. My question is how can I take the value from function so I can use it in more practical means.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJSON()
}

func getJSON(){
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let usdPrice = swiftyJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"].doubleValue
            print(usdPrice)


        }else{

        print("There was an error!")
        }
```

**let usdPrice** gets me the value so how can I take that from the function getJSON() and do something with it, for example attribute it to some label in Main.storyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the other answers are incorrect. Just returning a value will not work because you are getting the value from the completion closure of `dataTaskWithRequest`.

Having the statement `return usdPrice` should be a compiler error because the completion closure does not have a return value.

You'll need to add your own completion closure to `getJSON` that gets the double as a parameter.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getJSON { (usdPrice) -> Void in
        // do something with usdPrice
        print(usdPrice)
    }
}

func getJSON(completion: (Double) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let usdPrice = swiftyJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"].doubleValue
            completion(usdPrice)
        } else {
            print("There was an error!")
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function needs to return the value as a result of its execution. For more details check out this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID160

Comment: That won't work. See Clever Error's answer for a detailed explanation as to why it won't work.

Comment: Well printing out the value wont work for sure. My answer is correct, but not complete.

Comment: No, your answer is wrong. A function that uses an async method like dataTaskWithRequest cannot return a value as the function result. No way, no how. You have to refactor the function to take a completion block, as outlined in Clever Error's answer.

Comment: My answer is correct in the part that you can not "extract value from function" by printing out. The correct approach is to change the function so that it returns value. The remaining part which you pointed out is what people call "incomplete" ;)

Comment: You said "The correct approach is to change the function so that it returns value". **NO!** That is impossible. A function that uses an async method cannot return the result of that async method as the function result.

Answer (score -1):

You have to have a return value for the function.  The code below should work.

```
func getJSON() -> Double {

    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    var usdReturnValue : Double = 0.0
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{

            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let usdPrice = swiftyJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"].doubleValue
            print(usdPrice)
            usdReturnValue = usdPrice


        }else{

        print("There was an error!")
        }
    }
    return usdReturnValue
}
```

Comment: That won't work. See Clever Error's answer for a detailed explanation as to why it won't work.